# How to assign a value to the last value of a column is the easiest?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

I want to assign a value to the last value of column `B`. In addition to the following two methods, is there an easier way?

```
df.at[df.index[-1], 'B'] = 1
```

```
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'B'] = 1
```

Using `df.iloc[-1]['B']` will bring warnings.

`df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('B')]` is the answer I want.

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('B')] = 1
```

```
df.iloc[-1]['B'] = 1
```

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mixture of labeled indexing and indexed indexing, so I your solutions are nice already, but you could do:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('B')] = 1
```

Which is pretty neat, but it might be long but it's just the function name that's long.

Or why not just?

```
df.iloc[-1]['B'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. df.iloc[-1]['B'] = 1 is the result I want too.

Comment: @jaried Feel free to mark :)

Comment: Using `pd.iloc` will bring warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the index of column `B` then,

```
df.iloc[-1,1] = 1
```

Else,

```
df.iloc[-1].B = 1
```

Comment: He want's to use labeled indexing for columns.

Comment: I've added both cases.

Comment: That doesn't work...

Comment: Its working, I tried :)

Comment: df.iloc[-1].B = 1  this is what I want.

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani Using `pd.iloc` will bring warnings.

Comment: Inorder to discard warnings try `import warnings warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`